# Show that for $z $ a complex number, there exists a complex number $\alpha $, wiht $|\alpha |=1$ such that $\alpha z = |z |$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can  I show that for $z $ a complex number, there exists a complex number $\alpha $, wiht $|\alpha |=1$ such that $\alpha z = |z |$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** Use polar representation $z=re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is $\;\alpha={\overline z\over |z|}$ (the conjugate of z divided by $|z|$).

Can you see why?

Comment: Yes, since $\overline z z = |z |^2 $